# Create nuget package for multiple SDK projects

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, multiple-projects

I have 3 .net standard SDK projects(*Utils*, *Reporting* and *Testing*) that I want to pack them into one nuget package called *Shared* and upload it in my local package management system to be able to be used in my other projects. I was thinking to use the *csproj* file(s) to fill all the package information so I don't have to use *nuspec* file(s). One way I tried is to create a new .net standard project called *Shared* that references all the first 3 projects and only fill the *Shared.csproj*.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
     <Copyright>Copyright (c) Me</Copyright>
     <GeneratePackageOnBuild>False</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
     <SkipCopyBuildProduct>true</SkipCopyBuildProduct>
     <GenerateDependencyFile>False</GenerateDependencyFile>
     <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
     <DebugType>none</DebugType>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
     <ProjectReference Include="..\Utils.csproj" />
     <ProjectReference Include="..\Reporting.csproj" />
     <ProjectReference Include="..\Testing.csproj" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I've tried this msbuild command:

```
dotnet msbuild -t:pack=Shared.csproj;-p:Configuration=Release;PackageOutputPath=.\release;
```

and this nuget cli command:

```
nuget pack Shared.csproj -Build -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop Configuration=Release
```

but they don't work. I'm not sure which one is more suited.

Are there more suited alternatives?

**Later edit**: I've added my code to [github](https://github.com/MisiM/SharedDemo) with @mu88's suggestion to not create a project only for grouping my other projects but I don't get the 3 projects in my nupkg's libs folder. Do I also specify each project in the dependencies.group section?

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally recommend using a `.nuspec` file - using a project only as a container to ship multiple assemblies together without any behavior at all doesn't seem right to me.
Such a `.nuspec` would look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>My.Package</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <description>My package</description>
        <authors>Me</authors>
        <dependencies>
            <group targetFramework="netstandard2.0" />
        </dependencies>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="*\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\*.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.0" />
    </files>
</package>
```

And you have to call `nuget pack .\.nuspec` (using PowerShell).

The newer approach would be to not use `.nuspec` at all, but ship the three projects as three independent NuGet packages.

Comment: So you would create only a .nuspec file directly in the solution?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I would do

Comment: Using this command `nuget pack Shared\Shared.nuspec -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop Configuration=Release` it doesn't add anything in the lib folder from the nupkg. Do I have to specify them in the nuspec dependencies section? If so what is the format?

Comment: Did you build your solution before? If not, please update your question with your current version, folder structure, etc. (or provide it via GitHub repo). There should be no need to add additional parameters like `IncludeReferenceProjects`, etc.

Comment: I've updated my question and added a git example.

Comment: Update line 16 in your `Shared.nuspec` to this: `<file src="..\*\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\*.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.0" />`